# Ruby S3 Multipart pause and resume (add a part after calling close)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm using the `aws-sdk` gem and I'm trying to basically upload a really large file (it takes 2 days).

The file is uploaded in chunks but sometimes the script will crash and I would like to resume uploading (the next chunk).

During uploading we want to close `close` the multipart upload (so we can access the s3 data that has been uploaded so far).

Is it possible to add a part after the multipart upload is closed? (say the next day) basically resuming the upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a part after the multipart upload is closed?
>   (say the next day) basically resuming the upload?

Not as such, but you can simulate the affect you desire.

### Background

[Uploading Objects Using Multipart Upload API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) *allows you to upload a single object as a set of parts*:

> Each part is a contiguous portion of the object's data. You can upload
>   these object parts independently and in any order. If transmission of
>   any part fails, you can retransmit that part without affecting other
>   parts. **After all parts of your object are uploaded, Amazon S3
>   assembles these parts and creates the object.** *[emphasis mine]*

This is further detailed in [Complete Multipart Upload](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadComplete.html):

> You first initiate the multipart upload and then upload all parts
>   using the Upload Parts operation (see Upload Part). [...] **Upon receiving this request, Amazon S3
>   concatenates all the parts in ascending order by part number to create
>   a new object.** [...] You must ensure the parts list is complete,
>   this operation concatenates the parts you provide in the list. [...] *[emphasis mine]*

That is, the upload operation is finalized here and cannot be resumed by [uploading another part](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPart.html). (Technically speaking the `upload ID` required for any operation on an initiated multipart upload is not available/valid anymore).

### Solution

You can simple initiate a new multipart upload and upload your previously uploaded S3 object as the first part of this new multipart object by means of the [Upload Part - Copy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html) operation, which *Uploads a part by copying data from an existing object as data source*.